# Easiest way to encapsulate a HTML5 webpage into an android app?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, generator

We have developed a large web-based, responsive HTML5 data visualization that works nicely on PCs as well as on mobile devices. There's one thing though that is a bit annoying (on mobile devices), which is the fact that you always see some parts of the browser and therefore never get a clean fullscreen user experience.

We don't want to throw away the benefits of a platform-independant web-based HTML5 application, of course, but nevertheless we thought of offering an additional Android "app" to our customers, whose only purpose is to show our web application in fullscreen, without any title bars or menus etc. This would be just as functional and easy-to-work-with as our web app in a browser, but it would be a kind of *polished* version of it. I'm not an Android developer, but I see many many Android apps out there that are basically just a container for a browser window (webview?).

Although it's tempting to take a look at android development, I wonder if there is a tool or some kind of *generator* that produces such a pseudo-app by just giving a URL and maybe an icon? That would be perfect and totally sufficient for our purpose (and probably for others, too).

Update: Danilo recommended PhoneGap, which is great, but it might be a little bit over the top in my case as I only need to *show* a frameless browser window and do not need to run a web server with a node app on the phone itself.

Comment: Do have some experience with android?  The website online contains Js/Jquery and HTML?

Comment: I looked into it back in the days of 1.{something}, but I'd probably need to start from the beginning. And yes, the frontend is pure HTML and JS.

Comment: Are you willing to store the website local on the device or working with a https link?

Comment: The frontend is not a node project but an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to run and render on our server, so I would like to simply "plant" a link to our site in the app.

Comment: If you want I can give you some code for android Studio to create a webview app. The only thing you need to do is to change the link then. What is minSdkVersion you want to use?

Comment: Thank you, that would be perfect! A simply "Hello World" with a webview would have been the next thing I would have looked up myself, I thought it might be worth asking if there's a way to go *without* installing an Android Development environment. But I will happily do that, of course. I think the minimum version can safely be as high as Lollipop (5) or even a bit higher, if there are some nice features that come with that. Older devices can still use a normal browser to use our software.

Comment: It is smart to ask. Adobe is think useful. I have tried it myself and I preferred writing my own code I think Lollipop 5 is high enough because the people how will be using your app will be small. If possible I would say to you prefer android 4.4. That will reach the most users and everting will be compatible. Should I post is as answer? A basic project?

Comment: 4.4 is fine! If you want to post the basic steps to build a simple project, I will mark this as my accepted answer. This will help many others, too, I think.

Comment: Okey I will do that.

Comment: See my answer I hope you understand it. If you have any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to start a basic project that loads a simple HTML page.

If you create a new project choice for *Empty Activity*

First you will need to define your layout. You need to add a Webview layout to your Activity_main.xml

***Activity_main.xml is located under res -> layout***

This your Webview layout:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

The parent layout-tag needs to be `<RelativeLayout`

The second thing you need to do is to define what permissions you need you can do this in the AndroidManifest.xml

***AndroidMainfest.xml is located under manifest***

You need to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If you forgot these permission it will give you an error because he can't find the webpage even its a local file this permission is needed.

One problem with webview is that if you rotate your phone your activity will be restarted. That is not user-friendly so will lock the view to portrait.
So what we need to do is this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

So your AndroidManifest will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- ATTENTION: This data URL was auto-generated. We recommend that you use the HTTP scheme.
              TODO: Change the host or pathPrefix as necessary. -->
            <data
                android:host="[ENTER-YOUR-HTTP-HOST-HERE]"
                android:pathPrefix="/main"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Now will add the java code to the MainActivity to load the webpage we want:

***MainActivity.java is located under java -> [YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME]***

The first line we will define our class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

There in will we write some functions, the first function is to create the webview.

We declare a private var Webview. To write less code.

```
private WebView view;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser() {});
        view.loadUrl("HERE_YOUR_LINK");
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
}
```

If you want to load a local file the link will be something like this:

```
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

If you want to load a website like google it will be:

```
    view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Later on I will say where you need to locate your local HTML files that you want to load.

If you have something on your site like a link `mailto:`. It think you would like if people click on that it will open the Gmail app or an other email app. You can do that by creating a `OverrideUrlLoading` methode.

```
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
               if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:") || url.startsWith("https://youtu")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
     }
}
```

Like you can say I have also add `url.startsWith("https://youtu")`. I have personally because I find it user-friendly that you link to a Youtube video it will open in the Youtube app because people can then view it in full screen.

The only function we need is what do to if people click back on their phone.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack(); //method goback()
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

You need to add those lines to your build.gradle:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

So it will look something like this:

```
//here is so more code in the file
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you want to load local files instead of a website that is also possible. 
But where do I need to place them?

You need to create a map called assets.

Where will that map be located. Go to your file-explore on your PC
navigate to this:

***YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME -> app -> src -> main***

In that folder you will create a map `assets` and there in a map `www` there in you will paste your files

If you have any questions please respond

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check some existing webview based framework, for instance:

[Adobe Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/)

It will help you to generate an app that is compatible with different devices and platforms (including iOS). You can easily find documentation online, e.g., to make it fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising, I'll take a look at that.